# A code-based registration vs a design time registration in the context of the IoC

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, registration, ioc-container, dependency-inversion

What is the difference between the code-based registration and a design time registration in the context of the IoC?

I met the concepts [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/unity-container) while learning the IoC, DIP, DI and IoC containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning a little bit more about the IoC I come to a conclusion that the code-based registration is about registering the types with the help of an explicit code and the design time registration is about registering the types with the help of the C# attributes.